# Disable one NIC for Windows 10 user and leave another enabled?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, network-adapter

Is it possible to create a user in Windows 10 who has permission to install/uninstall programs, but does not have permission to enable one of the NICs on the system? I want one of the NICs to remain enabled, but remove permission from him for one of the NICs

Comment: So the system has multiple NICs and you don't want that user to fiddle with it or do you want to disable that NIC just for that one specific user and have it enable or every other use?

Comment: @Seth I don't want that user to be able to use traffic through one of the NICs, The system will have two users, an admin, and another user.

Comment: I don't think such a setup is possible with default windows tools. You'd need at least some additional software that e.g. enables you to setup a user specific route. As the scenario sounds kind of strange maybe you could give some more details on it or maybe try to look at it from a different angle to find an easier solution? The question is why there is a connection an admin/application on that computer should use while a normal user shouldn't and why that user can use the system in the first place in that case?

Comment: @seth I did some research today and it seems like it would be possible with windows 10 pro. I would setup a limited user, who does not have permission to enable/disable nics. I would then give him permission for install/uninstall.

Comment: You can only enable/disable the NIC for the whole system. So if the admin logs in he'd have to manually enable the NIC and remember to disable it before he logs out for the scenario you described. At least to my knowledge.